# conditional operator in linq sql

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Is it possible to have a conditional operator in linq in asp.net? I have tried this piece of code but it shows:

```
   The name BusinessInstance and LocalityMaster1 is not in a scope on the left hand side of 'equal' Consider swaping the expression on either side of 'equals'.
```

I need the result as BusinessName,(LocalityName/BusinessAddress),CityName. My sql is as follows:

```
from BusinessInstanceInfoKeys in db.utblYPBusinessInstanceInfoKeys.Where(x=> x.BusinessName.Contains(term))
join CityMaster in db.utblCityMasters
on BusinessInstanceInfoKeys.CityID equals CityMaster.CityID

let Address = BusinessInstanceInfoKeys.LocalityID != null
              ? from LocalityMaster1 in db.utblLocalityMasters
                join BusinessInstance in db.utblYPBusinessInstanceInfoKeys
                  on BusinessInstance.LocalityID equals LocalityMaster1.LocalityID
                select new 
                {
                    LocalityMaster1.LocalityName 
                }
              : BusinessInstanceInfoKeys.BusinessAddress
select new
{
    LocalityName = BusinessInstanceInfoKeys.BusinessName + ",(" + Address + ")" + "," + CityMaster.CityName
};
```

Can anyone suggest the right way?

Comment: Can you please edit your sample so it have more readable names... `objutblutblYP` is somewhat long and hard to read.

Comment: What do you mean by it is not working? Do you get an error, if so what is it? Or do you get an unexpected result?

Comment: I have edited the question please refer to it

Comment: Please include as much details as you can. Like in a bug report include what you expect, what you did and what actually happened. Also include the tech you used. Just Sal and linq narrows out to 3 mainstream tech and another dozen or so vendor implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the error, replace this:

```
on BusinessInstance.LocalityID equals LocalityMaster1.LocalityID
```

with this:

```
on LocalityMaster1.LocalityID equals BusinessInstance.LocalityID
```

---

Also, you can include a ternary expression inside of a `let`, but there may be a couple issues:

- If you're querying directly against the database (i.e. Entity Framework), I don't know that it will be able to produce meaningful SQL from the ternary expression, so it may throw an exception.
- Both conditions in the ternary expression must return the same data type. Yours do not appear to.

---

Based on your comments, and if at least one record will be returned if the query below is run, you can try this. *(I'm assuming* `LocalityName` *and* `BusinessAddress` *are both strings.)*

```
let Address = BusinessInstanceInfoKeys.LocalityID != null
              ? (from LocalityMaster1 in db.utblLocalityMasters
                 join BusinessInstance in db.utblYPBusinessInstanceInfoKeys
                   on BusinessInstance.LocalityID equals LocalityMaster1.LocalityID
                 select LocalityMaster1.LocalityName).FirstOrDefault()
              : BusinessInstanceInfoKeys.BusinessAddress
```

Comment: it shows like the type of conditional operator cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion

Comment: so what can be the solution to this as I am new to Linq

Comment: Returning data tyle is varchar(512) and again it shows `Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' and 'string' `